# sending Iplimage using sockets

Tags: c++, c, qt, sockets, opencv

I am trying to capture frames from a Logitech HD cam connected to a Raspberry Pi through usb, the RP is running arch linux and I am using OpenCV C api and a TCP client.

The TCP server is running c++(QT) under ubuntu.

I am storing the frame->imageData in a buffer and then send the data in the buffer.

this is a proof of concept that I can save a frame to a buffer then reconstruct a new frame which is tmpbuffer from the buffer,actually this code is running perfectly:

```
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
cvNamedWindow( "mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    int i =1;

   while ( 1 ) {
     // Get one frame
     IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
     CvSize size;
     size.height = 480;
  size.width = 640;
     IplImage* tmpframe = cvCreateImageHeader(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3); //create a new frame
     if ( !frame ) {
       //fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
       getchar();
       break;
     }else
     {
         //std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
         char buffer[frame->imageSize];
         snprintf(buffer,frame->imageSize,"%s",frame->imageData);
         //printf("frame->height= %s\n",buffer);

         tmpframe->imageData = buffer;
         printf("data %s\n",tmpframe->imageData);

         //snprintf(IDbuffer,10,"%d",frame->ID);
         //printf("frame->ID= %s\n",IDbuffer);
         i++;
     }
     cvShowImage( "mywindow", tmpframe );
```

Here is my client.c file:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
 #include <opencv/highgui.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>


void error(char *msg)
{
 perror(msg);
 exit(0);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

int sockfd,portno,n;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
 struct hostent *server;


 if(argc <3)
 {
  fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname portname port\n",argv[0]);
  exit(0);
 }

 portno = atoi(argv[2]);
 sockfd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM,0);

 if(sockfd < 0)
 {
  error("ERROR OPENING SOCKET");
 }

 server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
 if(server == NULL)
 {
  fprintf(stderr,"ERROR,NO SUCH HOST\n");
  exit(0);
 }

 bzero((char*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

 bcopy((char*)server->h_addr,(char*)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

 if(connect(sockfd,&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
 {
  error("ERROR CONNECTING");
 }
    CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
       // Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
        int i =1;

       while ( 1 ) {
         // Get one frame
         IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
         if ( !frame ) {
           //fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
           getchar();
           break;
         }else
         {
             i++;
         }

         char *msg = frame->imageData;
         char buffer[frame->imageSize];
         bzero (buffer,frame->imageSize);
         snprintf(buffer,frame->imageSize,"%s",msg);
 n=write(sockfd,buffer,frame->imageSize);
 if(n <0)
 {
  error("ERROR READING FROM SOCKET");
 }
 //printf("%s\n",buffer);


 }
return 0;
}
```

and this is how I am receiving data on my server:

```
void HostConnector::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

    CvSize size;
    size.height = 480;
    size.width = 640;
    IplImage *frame = cvCreateImageHeader(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);


    frame->imageData = Data.data();
    cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );

}
```

But the server is crashing !!
a `segmentation fault` at

```
cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues I see without real close examination of the code:

- You are using `printf(3)`-style functions to format binary data. That is wrong<sup>TM</sup>. The length of the resulting string would not be the same as the length of the image, and binary data might have zero bytes in the middle, or not have zero terminator.
- You are using temporary buffer (`char buffer[frame->imageSize]`) outside of its scope - that is probably the cause of the segmentation fault.

Comment: the segmentation fault is on the server not the client. how could using a temporary buffer on the client affect the server??

Comment: Oh, didn't see `cvShowImage` in the server code. But judging by your code, `frame->imageData` probably points to a messed up/corrupted representation of the image. And that temp buffer on the client is still a problem.

Comment: look , the first code is a proof of concept that I can save a frame to a buffer then reconstruct a new frame which is tmpbuffer from the buffer(this code is working fine), the second code is the client code where I am trying to send frames captured from the Cam , the third code is how I receive frames on the server.I don't understand how to format binary data since I am new to C.

Comment: You don't need to format the binary data. If imgData is a contiguous array of bytes, just send it out the socket directly. You don't need to copy it to a different buffer.

Comment: I did , but the same error appears , I think the problem is how I receive data on the server using Qt , but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you confirmed you are receiving the same amount of data you are sending? As it stands, your receiving code expects enough data for a 640x480 image. If you do not receive that much data, cvShowImage will walk off the end of the buffer you give it and boom! segfault.

Comment: If you have changed the sending code in client.c, please post the updated code. As it is, this line is likely to cause serious issues:snprintf(buffer,frame->imageSize,"%s",msg);

Comment: @ShaunMarko yes I think that I am receiving less data , after debugging, I found that the char * received is incomplete.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22340/discussion-between-ahmed-kato-and-shaun-marko)